# I am getting an error General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: magento-1.9, error, join, group

I have this code

```
 $orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
    $ordercollection = $orderModel->getCollection()
        ->setPageSize(20)
        ->setCurPage(1)
        ->join(array('item' => 'sales/order_item'), 'main_table.entity_id = item.order_id');
    $ordercollection->addFilterToMap('large_total', 'SUM(subtotal_invoiced)');

    $ordercollection->getSelect()->columns('SUM(subtotal_invoiced) as large_total');
    $ordercollection->getSelect()->where('SUM(subtotal_invoiced) >= 200');
    $ordercollection->getSelect()->group('main_table.customer_email');
```

If I take out the line

```
    $ordercollection->getSelect()->where('SUM(subtotal_invoiced) >= 200');
```

then it seems to work fine.  I am not sure what I doing wrong here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL aggregate functions (like SUM) cannot be used as part of a WHERE clause because the values aren't calculated early enough. Instead there is an additional clause called a HAVING clause.

```
$ordercollection->getSelect()->columns('SUM(subtotal_invoiced) as large_total');
$ordercollection->getSelect()->group('main_table.customer_email');
$ordercollection->getSelect()->having('SUM(subtotal_invoiced) >= 200');
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT A.CurrentProfit - B.CurrentProfit
FROM kikingo_mt4.AccountLogs_Daily A
JOIN (
    SELECT CurrentProfit
    FROM kikingo_mt4.AccountLogs_Daily
    WHERE Date IN (select min(Date) from kikingo_mt4.AccountLogs_Daily where Date between current_date() and current_date() -7 )
    ) B
ON A.MT4Account = B.MT4Account
WHERE A.Date = MAX(Date)

//////// Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function ////////